# Why doesn't std::move on a std::unique_lock have any effect?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, move-semantics

I have the following C++(11) code:

```
#include <mutex>

void unlock(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> && ulock)
{
}

int main(void)
{
    std::mutex m;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock(m);

    unlock(std::move(ulock));

    if (ulock.mutex() == &m || ulock.owns_lock())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I can't figure out is why the mutex is still held after the return from `unlock()`. My expectation is that the `std::move()` causes the lock to go out of scope (and become unlocked by the destructor) upon return from the call to `unlock()`. At the very least, it seems like the `std::move()` should have caused `ulock` to become "unbound" from the mutex `m`.

What am I missing?

Comment: `std::move` doesn't itself move anything anywhere. It simply casts an lvalue to an rvalue reference, allowing it to be an argument of move constructors and such. Those in turn may steal the internals of (what they think to be) the temporary. But your code doesn't call any of them. `unlock(std::move(ulock));` is an elaborate no-op.

Comment: Define `unlock` to take the `std::unique_lock` by value, then move into it, to see the effects

Comment: I had assumed that std::move() invoked the move constructor for the unique_lock. It sounds like that's not the case... Rather, the rvalue reference in `unlock()` is a "notification" of sorts that *it* can use the move constructor should it so choose (if that makes sense).

Comment: Yes, precisely. `std::move` is a permission to move, not the act thereof. `std::move(T& v)` simply does `return static_cast<T&&>(v);` and nothing more.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: You should('ve) post(ed) your comment as an answer. I'd accept it as you were the first.

Answer (score 14):

```
void unlock(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> && ulock)
```

Here `ulock` is a **reference**. A special kind of reference, but still a reference. It is just an alias for another object. Its creation does not involve creation of a new object, or any kind of ownership transfer. Likewise, end of its lifetime does not lead to any destructor call, it just means that you lost the alias for referring to some other object (not that it matters, since the function is ending anyway).

If you want to transfer ownership, you need an **object**, so pass by value instead of by reference:

```
void unlock(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock)
```

Now, you will have to `move` the original lock, since `std::unique_lock` does not support copy construction, only move construction.